# Unwanted class attribute from using simple xml

Tags: java, xml

I'm currently using the simple XML library, and the tutorial didn't have a runnable example for ElementLists. http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

I have an example class:

```
@Root
public class Example {

@ElementList
private List<String> text;

@Attribute
private int index;

public Example() {
   super();
}  

public Example(List<String> text, int index) {
   this.text = text;
   this.index = index;
}

public List<String> getMessage() {
  return text;
}

public int getId() {
  return index;
}
}
```

And a simple class for running:

```
public class M {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();

    l.add("f");
    l.add("f");

    Example example = new Example(l, 123);
    File result = new File("example.xml");

    serializer.write(example, result);
}

}
```

The XML that I generate is:

```
<example index="123">
<text class="java.util.LinkedList">
  <string>f</string>
  <string>f</string>
</text>
</example>
```

Why am I getting the class="java.util.LinkedList"? I'm confused on how remove this attribute.

Comment: Try with `@ElementList(name="list")` annotation or use any name.

Comment: Try with `@ElementArray private String[] text`

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).

Comment: I tried your suggestion via private String[] text. I edited my M.java with   String[] stockArr = {"fd", "fd"};
  
  Example example = new Example(stockArr, 123);              I then got a java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection].

Comment: But yeah, I did the tutorial but it didn't give an example on how to generate the XML in a main file, when you're using a listelement.

Comment: `ClassCastException` because you haven't replaced it everywhere means in constructor, instance variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on the same problem and I got a way to avoid the 'class' attribute.

Instead of using @ElementList like this:

```
@ElementList(name="Files", entry="File")
```

You can use @Path annotation with the @ElementList as follows:

```
@Path(value="Files")
@ElementList(inline=true, entry="File")
```

Comment: Simple solution and worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VisitorStrategy to intercept the serialization of the object.

```
Strategy strategy = new VisitorStrategy(new Visitor() {

    @Override
    public void write(Type type, NodeMap<OutputNode> node) throws Exception {
        if ("text".equals(node.getName())){
            node.remove("class");
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Implementation for an @ElementList List, example :
LinkedList instead of List.

```
@ElementList
private LinkedList<String> texts;
```

This will  avoid class attribute not wanted.